# Peskin and Schroeder eqn 9.14

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, momentum, path-integral, integration

I am not familiar with functional integral, and in the text like $$\int D\phi D\pi \exp [i\int^T_od^4x(\pi\dot{\phi}-\frac{1}{2}\pi^2-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2-V(\phi))].\tag{9.14}$$ I try to compile it but get:
$$\int D\phi\left[ \prod_{x,t}\int d\pi\ \exp [i\epsilon^4(\pi\dot{\phi}-\frac{1}{2}\pi^2)] \right] \exp([i\int^T_od^4x(-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2-V(\phi))]$$
$$=\int D\phi \left[\prod_{x,t}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{i\epsilon^4}} \exp [i\epsilon^4\frac{\dot{\phi}^2}{2}] \right] \exp([i\int^T_od^4x(-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2-V(\phi))]$$
$$=\int D\phi \left[\prod_{x,t}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{i\epsilon^4}}\right] \exp[i\int^T_od^4x(\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2-V(\phi))].$$
I know things were terrible wrong, but what is it?

Comment: Since $<\phi(\mathbf{x},t)|\phi(\mathbf{y}, t)> = \delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})$, additional $(2\pi)^3$ will enter in the denominator I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP's infinitely many [Gaussian integrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) of the momentum field are essentially the correct method. The infinite product in OP's last line is usually tucked away by normalizing the path integral appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer